# Foreign key is null while using Hibernate One to One mapping

Tags: java, sql, xml, hibernate, exception

I'm trying to work with hibernate and I have a class question and a class answer, and there's One To One relation between them, the code is successfully running but the foreign key is null, I don't know why. Here's my code

```java
package io.com.learnHibernate;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="question")
public class Question {

    
    @Id
    private int questionId;
    private String question;
    
    
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "question")
    private Answer answer;
    
    
    public Question() {
        super();
    }
    public Question(int questionId, String question, io.com.learnHibernate.Answer answer) {
        super();
        this.questionId = questionId;
        this.question = question;
        answer = answer;
    }
    public Answer getAnswer() {
        return answer;
    }
    public void setAnswer(Answer answer) {
        answer = answer;
    }
    public int getQuestionId() {
        return questionId;
    }
    public void setQuestionId(int questionId) {
        this.questionId = questionId;
    }
    public String getQuestion() {
        return question;
    }
    public void setQuestion(String question) {
        this.question = question;
    }

}
```

```java
package io.com.learnHibernate;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="answer")
public class Answer {
    
    @Id
    private int aId;
    private String answer;
    
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn
    private Question question ;
    
    public Answer() {
        super();
    }
    public Answer(int aId, String answer) {
        super();
        this.aId = aId;
        this.answer = answer;
    }
    public int getaId() {
        return aId;
    }
    public void setaId(int aId) {
        this.aId = aId;
    }
    public String getAnswer() {
        return answer;
    }
    public void setAnswer(String answer) {
        this.answer = answer;
    }
}
```

my `hibernate.cfg.xml` file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM 
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
   <session-factory>
   
      <property name = "hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</property>
      
      <property name = "hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver </property>
      
      <!-- Assume test is the database name -->
      
      <property name = "hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/aliens </property>
      
      <property name = "hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
      
      <property name = "hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
            <property name = "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
        <property name = "show_sql">true</property>
      <!-- List of XML mapping files -->
                 <mapping  class= "io.com.learnHibernate.Question"/>
      <mapping  class= "io.com.learnHibernate.Answer"/>

     
   </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

and my main function

```java
package io.com.learnHibernate;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.*;

import com.mysql.cj.xdevapi.SessionFactory;

/**
 * Hello world!
 *
 */
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
       //configuration
        Configuration conf=new Configuration();
        conf.configure("Hibernate.cfg.xml");
        org.hibernate.SessionFactory factory=conf.buildSessionFactory();
        
        
//creating answer 
        
        Answer a1=new Answer();
        a1.setaId(180);
        a1.setAnswer("my name is hafida");
        //creating question
        
        Question q1=new Question();
        q1.setQuestionId(3);
        q1.setQuestion("wht is your name?");
        q1.setAnswer(a1);
        
        //session 
        Session s=factory.openSession();
        Transaction tx=s.beginTransaction();
        
        //save
        s.save(q1);
          s.save(a1);

        tx.commit();
    //  s.close();
    //  factory.close();
            
    }
}
```

I expected to have the value of the foreign key inserted, but it's null

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to specify [cascade type](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#pc-cascade) in your entities mapping:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="answer")
public class Answer {
        
    @Id
    private int aId;
    private String answer;
        
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn
    private Question question;

    // ...
}


@Entity
@Table(name="question")
public class Question {
   
    @Id
    private int questionId;
    private String question;
       
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "question", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Answer answer;

    // ...
}
```

2. As you use [bidirectional @OneToOne](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-one-bidirectional), you should make both sides in-sync:

```java
Answer a1 = new Answer();
a1.setaId(180);
a1.setAnswer("my name is hafida");
        
Question q1 = new Question();
q1.setQuestionId(3);
q1.setQuestion("wht is your name?");

// make both sides in-sync
a1.setQuestion(q1);
q1.setAnswer(a1);
```

3. Then you can save it in this way:

```java
s.save(q1);

// you need not use s.save(a1);
// a1 will be saved due to propagation of the q1 entity's state
```